# Want to send excel as mail attachment through pl/sql procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, email-attachments, clob

When I send mail with attachment through procedure using clob to create data.
For small data it's working fine. But for large data it's misbehaving (alignment changing). can you help whether anything needs to done with the code.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE RPT AS 
  l_clob clob; 
  l_bfile   bfile;
    l_fhandle utl_file.file_type;
  l_buffer  VARCHAR2(8192);
v_count number;
 a_count number;
   k_count number;
     ka_count number;
      currentdate DATE;
     non_work_days_count number;
    BEGIN
   --preparing header
         dbms_lob.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE); 
 l_clob := l_clob 
      || 'Column1'|| ','
      || 'Column2' || ','
      || 'Column3' || ','
      || 'Column4' || ','
      || UTL_TCP.crlf;

 for crq in (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where id=1 ) loop
   /* Prepare Details data using Clob */   
 l_clob := l_clob 
      || to_clob(crq.COl1)|| ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL2) || ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL3) || ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL4) || ','
      || UTL_TCP.crlf;
      end loop; 

      for crq in (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where id=2 ) loop
    /* Prepare Details data using Clob */   
     l_clob := l_clob 
      || to_clob(crq.COl1)|| ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL2) || ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL3) || ','
      || to_clob(crq.COL4) || ','
      || UTL_TCP.crlf;
         end loop; 
    dbms_output.put_line('Sending mail with attachment ');
          ATTACHMENT_SEND(p_to=> 'req@Email.com',
            p_from=> 'req@Email.com',
            p_subject=> ' Report ',
            p_text_msg=>'Hi All',   
             p_attach_name =>'report_'||sysdate||'.csv',
            p_attach_mime =>'text/plain',
            p_attach_clob =>l_clob,
            p_smtp_host=>'host.com');


   dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob); 


      END RPT;
```

Also I observe when character length reach 32000 it's breaking(leaving remaining data).

The data in the created excel attachment is having alignment issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found a different approach which worked as a gem for me(which can handle lakhs of records). I thought it would help someone someday.

Steps:

1)Created a directory (in which the expected excel is stored).
2)Write the output of the select statement into the above file.
3)Pick the file at above location and send it in the mail attachment.

Note: if any one needs SMTP code part or any assistance let me know

Comment: Before someone asks from you, Its better to post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

`||` concatenation limits you up to 4000 in Oracle SQL while limits to 32000 in PL/SQL. You may try [DBMS_LOB.APPEND][1] procedure to concatenate long CLOBs. So you may try to convert your code to -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RPT AS
l_clob              clob; 
l_bfile             bfile;
l_fhandle           utl_file.file_type;
l_buffer            VARCHAR2(8192);
v_count             number;
a_count             number;
k_count             number;
ka_count            number;
currentdate         DATE;
non_work_days_count number;
BEGIN
   --preparing header
      dbms_lob.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE); 
      l_clob := l_clob 
      || 'Column1'|| ','
      || 'Column2' || ','
      || 'Column3' || ','
      || 'Column4' || ','
      || UTL_TCP.crlf;

for crq in (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where id=1 ) loop
   /* Prepare Details data using Clob */   
l_clob := DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
              DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
                  DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
                      DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl1) || ',')
                     ,to_clob(crq.COL2) || ',')
                 ,to_clob(crq.COL3) || ',')
             ,to_clob(crq.COL4) || ',' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
      end loop; 

for crq in (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table where id=2 ) loop
    /* Prepare Details data using Clob */   
l_clob := DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
              DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
                  DBMS_LOB.APPEND(
                      DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl1) || ',')
                     ,to_clob(crq.COL2) || ',')
                 ,to_clob(crq.COL3) || ',')
             ,to_clob(crq.COL4) || ',' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
      end loop; 
dbms_output.put_line('Sending mail with attachment ');

ATTACHMENT_SEND(p_to          => 'req@Email.com',
                p_from        => 'req@Email.com',
                p_subject     => ' Report ',
                p_text_msg    =>'Hi All',   
                p_attach_name =>'report_'||sysdate||'.csv',
                p_attach_mime =>'text/plain',
                p_attach_clob =>l_clob,
                p_smtp_host   =>'host.com');

dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob); 

END RPT;

[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i997432
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit, Thanks for the answer. It's giving below error."Error(85,23): PLS-00222: no function with name 'APPEND' exists in this scope"

Comment: If I am using as DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl1) || ',');  DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl2) || ',');   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl3) || ',');     DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_clob
                                     ,to_clob(crq.COl4) || ','  || UTL_TCP.crlf);     Then no error but in the excel it should show 280 records, but only 230 records are comming

Comment: Are 230 records violating 32000 limit?

Comment: Yes @ankit. They were violating